# Django Using Slug Field for Detail URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm attempting to setup my site so that the url for my job-detail will use a slug field instead of a pk. It's telling me that it cannot find my job with the given slug (which is an int, 147).

## Update:

After looking at the DetailView description at https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/ I realized there is a `slug_field` attribute for `DetailView`. My new view looks like:

```
class JobDetailView(CacheMixin, DetailView):
    model = Job
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

## Question:

[image]

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^careers$', views.job_list, name='job-list'),
    url(r'^careers/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobDetailView.as_view(), name='job-detail'),
]
```

view:

```
class JobDetailView(CacheMixin, DetailView):
    model = Job
    pk_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the superclass
        object = super(JobDetailView, self).get_object()
        # Return the object
        return object

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = super(JobDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return object
```

model:

```
class Job(UpdateAble, PublishAble, models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    facility = models.ForeignKey('Facility')
    recruiter = models.ForeignKey('Recruiter')
    title = models.TextField()
    practice_description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    public_description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")

    objects = JobManager()

    def get_next(self, **kwargs):
        jobs = Job.objects.published()
        next = next_in_order(self, qs=jobs)
        if not next:
            next = jobs[0]
        return next

    def get_prev(self, **kwargs):
        jobs = Job.objects.published()
        prev = prev_in_order(self, qs=jobs)
        if not prev:
            prev = jobs[len(jobs)-1]
        return prev

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.facility}; {self.title}'
```

manager:

```
class JobManager(models.Manager):

    def published(self):
        return super(JobManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_published=True).order_by('facility__name', 'title')
```

Comment: Why is your slug field an int? That defeats the whole purpose of having a slug. Also note that both your `get_object` and `get` methods are pointless, you should remove them.

Comment: It's an int because I am using an ID from other systems as my slug. I have good reasons for doing this. 2) I was using overriding those methods at one point to achieve something and didn't pay attention to the override not being necessary afterward. I'll remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to define `pk_url_kwarg` at all, and in fact by doing so you have confused things leading to the object not being found.

As you can see from [the default implementation of `get_object`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/SingleObjectMixin/#get_object), the view normally looks for either a `pk` or `slug` kwarg in the URL; whichever it finds will be used for the lookup. But by setting `pk_url_kwarg` to `slug`, you're telling the view to get the URL kwarg named "slug" but *use it to look up against the PK field*, which obviously won't work.

Just remove that attribute altogether, and Django will detect your slug kwarg and use it to correctly look up against the slug field.

Comment: Okay, I see that now on ccbv. I updated my question to reflect how to make it work even if they are using a custom slug field, which is actually what I want to do.